# Кеширование данных в RecyclerView

Tags: android, realm

Всем привет.
Есть приложение, в котором я парсю JSON с сайта и вывожу полученные данных в RecyclerView. Проблема в том, что при закрытии приложения и последующем открытии без интернета список пустой.
Я начал сохранять все данные в Realm, но я так и не понял, как эти данные в итоге-то выводить в RecyclerView и сделать кеш приложения.

Comment: `adapter.setData(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(DataModel.class).findAll()); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` Если очень грубо. А так - дополните вопрос деталями - не понятно что именно у вас затруднеие вызывает. Как адаптер создать? Как данные из БД отобразить?

Comment: Да, как их отобразить.
Сейчас у меня есть класс MyDataRealm, который содержит поля(Заголовок, сам текст и т.д.).
Я во фрагменте делаю парсинг, создаю List<MyDataRealm>, передаю его в адаптер и там вывожу заголовки в TextView карточек.
Как отображать их из БД, а не из передаваемого List<MyDataRealm>?
Если нужен код - могу отправить, но код чего? Адаптера RecyclerView?

Comment: Алгоритм - вы из сети получаете данные, пишете их в реалм, потом из реалма достаете в свой List и его сетите в адаптер. ЮрийСПб дал код для получения данных из реалма и их отображения

Comment: Пытаюсь это сделать, но пока не понимаю, как засетить лист в адаптер? По коду ЮрияСПБ не получается.

Comment: Я получаю данные в AsyncTask, записываю их в Realm, потом в этом же AsyncTask из реалма достаю данные в  List<MyDataRealm>.
И customAdapterRealm = new CustomAdapterRealm(view.getContext(), data_listRealm);
Но данные не остаются при повторном запуске без интернета.

P.S. почему вы пишете ответы на вопросы в комментариях, а не в ответах?